# Can I create JavaScript function in PHP looping

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make an alert using JavaScript. This is an example I have made `bls.hol.es`.
When I click first name will display an alert containing the first name. But it displays an alert containing the second name.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$arrayname=array('iqbal', 'rezza');
$arrayaddress=array('teloyo', 'karang rejo');
for ($x = 0; $x <= 1; $x++)
{
    $name=$arrayname[$x]; 
    $address=$arrayaddress[$x];   // indent consistently!!
?>

<script>
    function call()
    {
        var nik = "<?php echo $name ?>";    // semicolons not needed in the embedded PHP code
        var addres = "<?php echo $address ?>";   // indent consistently!!
        alert(nik+address);
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:call();"><?php echo $name ?></a>

<?php
} ?>
```

Whether this can be done my way?

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Don't do it this way.  Have .js grab the text inside the `<a></a>`.  An inline alert will be just fine -- no bloat.

Comment: in my example just a variable. i want to post 3 variable. Can use <a></a> ?

Comment: You can use the recursion to call the javascript function with php code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you're creating js function `call()` inside the loop, so technically you have two declarations of `call()` in resulting code. When you call the `call()` function, then both of them are processed.

I assume you want to use more logic in the `call()` in the future, so the solution would be to alter your js code to process the name as a parameter nad move it outside the loop like:

```
 function call(name){
     alert(name);
 }
```

and alter the link:

```
<a href="javascript:call('<?php echo $name;?>');"><?php echo $name;?></a>
```

Comment: in my example just a variable. i want to post 3 variable. Can use this way ?

Comment: @Iqbal you can make unlimited calls to the single function, but with our snippets, we are passing just one parameter at a time.

Comment: @Iqbal - df course - function call(name, secondName, address){} for example

Comment: @Iqbal You should add any new question details directly to the question itself via an edit.  This way, when future SO readers come to this page, they will quickly understand the "full story" (without reading comments) and the reason for the green tick / upvotes.

Comment: @Iqbal - you have to put the parameters into quotes - check my previous post

Answer (score 1):

Just loop the html with inline onclick using the php loop.

```html
<a onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">iqbal</a>
<a onclick="alert(this.innerHTML);">rezza</a>
```

Here's the php:

```
$arrayname=array('iqbal', 'rezza');
foreach($arrayname as $v){
    echo "<a onclick='alert(this.innerHTML);'>$v</a>";
    // or echo "<a onclick='alert($v);'>$v</a>";
}
```

---

The bottom line is, you don't want to write duplicate functions.  Write one function, call it as many times as you wish, and pass `$v` as a parameter to it, then you can do what ever you wish with the parameter inside the function.

If you are making a function call and want to send three variables at time, you can set it up like this in php:

```
<script>
function call(one,two,three){
    alert(one);
    alert(two);
    alert(three);
}
</script>
<?php
$array=[
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['d','e','f']
];

foreach($array as $a){
    echo "<a href=\"javascript:call('{$a[0]}','{$a[1]}','{$a[2]}');\">{$a[0]} and {$a[1]} and {$a[2]}</a>";
}
```

Comment: @Iqbal see my update for how to call the function with three parameters -- built by php

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with your code is the second pass through the loop redefines the `call()` function with the second name, so by the time it's been rendered in the browser window, only the second instance of the function is available to run.